# Logo not centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this template: http://www.responsivewebmobile.com/app/webroot/rwm_carousel_fullscreen/ (it's bootstrap 3)

Of course, made modifications as needed, ie, photos, text.

Am trying to add the logo to it, and to have it centered.

Nothing I do makes it centered.

Here's one variation I've tried:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="logo" class="span12">
    <img class="img-circle" src="url address here" />
</div>
```

Here's the css I've attached to logo id:

```
            z-index: 100;
        position:absolute;
       /* width: 100%; */
    margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto; 
        float:none;
```

Regardless of what I do, it simply doesn't center.

Any advice?

Comment: make a jsfiddle of your problem

Comment: you can't margin auto images

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sVCa4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/sVCa4/1/

Comment: @vico, ok, thanks for letting me know. what can I do instead?

Comment: You can do `position:absolute; left:0; right:0; margin:0 auto;`

Comment: @tgerry, doesn't work, I need `position:absolute` to lay over the photos.

Comment: @W.D., doesn't work. Just tried that now, without `z-index` and it doesn't show up. Tried it with `z-index` and it doesn't center.

Comment: You need `z-index` so the element will be placed over other elements. Make a `jsfiddle` demo.

Comment: @W.D., hm, I would have tried to make a jsfiddle if I knew how to, I guess. The idea was kinda overwhelming. Anyway, one of the answers worked, so, thankful for that. But thanks though!

Comment: @user2730725, for nothing. Glad you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 1;
```

To center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

How about just:

```
#logo {
 text-align:center;
}
```

See the fiddle - 
http://jsfiddle.net/UE5M5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this approch

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
<div id="logo" class="center">
    <img class="img-circle" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</div>
</div>


.center
{
margin:auto;
width:70%;
background-color:#b0e0e6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r6rQV/

Comment: hey, tried this, and it didn't work. Sorry. But thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is by-far the most useful trick I've learned about centering:

[**Read it here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/)

Shortly said, your logo needs to have these css attributes:

```
  {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -111 ; /* 1/2 the width of your logo */
  margin-top: -111; /*1/2 the height of your logo */

  }
```

I hope that helps!

p.s It works with everything that has a set height and width (ex. div tags)

Comment: hey, tried this, and it didn't work. Sorry. But thank you so much!

Comment: Ok..there seems to be another issue, then. Where exactly is your logo? If it is nested somewhere, get it out of there, try putting it directly after the start of the <body> tag.

Comment: it was actually underneath the <body> tag. Still is. But, no worries now. The solution from Charles worked. Just wanted to thank you. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
#lgoo {width: 100%;}
#logo img {margin: 0 auto; display: block;}
```

Comment: sorry, didn't try this since the one from Charles worked, but thank you so much!